# Adaptive Cards Not Displaying Outlook for Android/IOS

Tags: adaptive-cards

We have just started playing around with Adaptive cards and have them Posting to a Test API through Outlook for Web - these cards are not displaying in Outlook for IOS/Android though. Is there something special we need to do to get these to work in Outlook for Mobile versions?

To Test Outlook IOS/Android we sent a Standard sample copied from https://adaptivecards.io which did not display. We have Native Microsoft Sync Technology enabled. Apologies in advance if I have missed the obvious!

Sample copied from https://adaptivecards.io/designer which display correctly in Outlook for Web.

These cards do not display in Outlook for Android/IOS.

Comment: We are facing the same issue? Can you share your card JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Adaptive Cards to work on Outlook IOS you will need to get in touch with Microsoft Onboarding team and get your Originator ID whitelisted.  Outlook for Android is yet to be released.